# How to verify the signature of an application (exe) using x509?

Tags: validation, go, digital-signature, x509certificate

```
file, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
block, _ := pem.Decode(file)
cert, err := x509.ParseCertificate(block.Bytes)
```

I have the above code in my program, where I have an exe to verify the digital signature. I am passing the name of the exe as 'filename'. Both the program and the application file are in the same directory. But this piece of code expects a certificate file as it's argument, hence the 'block' here is getting a nil value, because of which the block.bytes is also nil. It's throwing an error here. How can I find a certificate file from an exe or find a way to validate an exe using x509 package?

Comment: You need to extract the signature from the executable. Either find a library that does it, or call signtool.

Comment: Google "*authenticode pe format*", it explains how a PE file is signed and where the signature is stored.

Comment: Hi @Marc I don't find a library to extract that signature, and I have implemented Wintrust, to verify the signature, but now I also want to validate the same by comparing the subject name or issuername for, eg:- Microsoft Corporation etc. This could be ideally accomplished by using x509 validation but not able to figure out how in golang.